# IF Nested IF Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

[image]

I will insert and fill columns "Mark" info dataframe with IF statement, but in row Duration(Mins) = "10.0" the result is None, dtypes columns Duration(Mins) is float64, thanks for your answer

```
import pandas as pd

# Define data as a dictionary
data = {
    'Alarm Name': ['Cell Down', '4G Down', '3G Down', '2G Down', 'Cell Unavailable', 'Partial Down', 'Signalling Down'],
    'Duration(Mins)': [3, 5.9, 10.1, 2.9, -12, 6, 10]
}

#Function
def mark(row):
    if row['Duration(Mins)'] >= 0:
        if row['Duration(Mins)'] < 3:
            return '0-3 Mins'
        elif row['Duration(Mins)'] < 6:
            return '3-6 Mins'
        elif row['Duration(Mins)'] < 10:
            return '6-10 Mins'
        elif row['Duration(Mins)'] > 10:
            return '>10 Mins'
    else:
        return 'Open'

df['Mark'] = df.apply(mark, axis=1)
```

Comment: Your else will also not catch it because the 10 is bigger than 0 and is included in the first if, but none of the ifs under it are including the 10. You have bigger than 10 and smaller than 10, but no if says equal to 10.

Comment: Looking at how this is setup I would change the line `elif row['Duration(Mins)'] < 10:` to `elif row['Duration(Mins)'] <= 10:` just so it also catches the case for 10 mins and still makes sense (you don't want to mark it as open if its value is 10 mins)

Comment: does fixing the = solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Does this fix your problem? You missed a = on the if that says 10 mins.

```
def mark(row):
    if row['Duration(Mins)'] >= 0:
        if row['Duration(Mins)'] < 3:
            return '0-3 Mins'
        elif row['Duration(Mins)'] < 6:
            return '3-6 Mins'
        elif row['Duration(Mins)'] < 10:
            return '6-10 Mins'
        elif row['Duration(Mins)'] >= 10:
            return '>=10 Mins'
    else:
        return 'Open'

df['Mark'] = df.apply(mark, axis=1)
```

in your version the case of Duration being exactly 10 wasn't captured.

Comment: but i will 10.0 in ">10 Mins" not "6-10 Mins"

Comment: i made an edit, does it work now as you like?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) if you need an efficient (vectorized) approach:

```
df["Mark"] = pd.cut(
    df["Duration(Mins)"],
    bins=[
        -float("inf"),
        0,
        3,
        6,
        10,
        float("inf"),
    ],
    labels=["Open", "0-3 Mins", "3-6 Mins", "6-10 Mins", "> 10 Mins"],
    right=False,
)
```

```
         Alarm Name  Duration(Mins)       Mark
0         Cell Down             3.0   3-6 Mins
1           4G Down             5.9   3-6 Mins
2           3G Down            10.1  > 10 Mins
3           2G Down             2.9   0-3 Mins
4  Cell Unavailable           -12.0       Open
5      Partial Down             6.0  6-10 Mins
6   Signalling Down            10.0  > 10 Mins
```

Note: column `"Mark"` will be of type [`pandas.Category`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html).